# How to properly setup a PHP while loop without duplicate data being repeated

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop

I have looked through countless previous questions and cannot find one identical to the issue I am having.  I have a working script which grabs the data I need from the database ok.

```
<?php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(colUser) AS userCount, colMonth as userMonth, colYear as userYear FROM MyTable GROUP BY userYear");
$newData = array();
$years = array();
$cnt = array();
while($selected_row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($years,$selected_row['userMonth']);
    $tmp_key = $selected_row['userYear'];

    array_push($cnt,$selected_row['userCount']);
    $newData[$tmp_key] = array(
       implode(',',$cnt)
    );
}
$jsonResult = json_encode($newData);


echo $jsonResult;
```

The output I need is

```
{
  "2018": ["292,181,1868,1074,2726,2213,2616,3269,1744,2839,1983,1689"],
  "2019": ["2179,2027,1948,2071,2323,1963,2721,4065,4626,4660,3783,3170"],
  "2020": ["4308,3307,6143,6795,1881"]
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
{
  "2018": ["292,181,1868,1074,2726,2213,2616,3269,1744,2839,1983,1689"],
  "2019": ["292,181,1868,1074,2726,2213,2616,3269,1744,2839,1983,1689,2179,2027,1948,2071,2323,1963,2721,4065,4626,4660,3783,3170"],
  "2020": ["292,181,1868,1074,2726,2213,2616,3269,1744,2839,1983,1689,2179,2027,1948,2071,2323,1963,2721,4065,4626,4660,3783,3170,4308,3307,6143,6795,1881"]
}
```

Also, if it is possible, a more ideal output would be (fill empty months with zero)

```
{
  "2018": ["292,181,1868,1074,2726,2213,2616,3269,1744,2839,1983,1689"],
  "2019": ["2179,2027,1948,2071,2323,1963,2721,4065,4626,4660,3783,3170"],
  "2020": ["4308,3307,6143,6795,1881,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"]
}
```

I sincerely thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you you storing your values as a single string inside an array? In other words, instead of `implode(','$cnt)`, you could just do `$newData[$tmp_key] = $cnt` - If you never want duplicate values, you need to keep a list of values that have already been used and make sure thye aren't added again. It would also help us a lot if we could see how your data is formatted before your while loop.

Comment: I have just started experimenting with JSON created PHP arrays.  I would not say I am new to arrays, but not exactly intermediate yet.  So if I am doing something improperly, I am unaware of it.

Comment: The data before the while loop is just that which is returned from the SQL query.  Nothing special.  Database just has year and month columns and then user ID.  I know that I could accomplish what I am wanting with a second query, but I am trying to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

With guidance from GrumpyCrouton, I was able to achieve the results I wanted with this.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(colUser) AS userCount, colMonth as userMonth, colYear as userYear FROM MyTable GROUP BY userYear");
$newData = array();
$years = array();
$cnt = array();
while($selected_row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($years,$selected_row['userMonth']);
    $tmp_key = $selected_row['userYear'];
    $newData[$tmp_key][] = $selected_row['userCount'];
}
$jsonResult = json_encode($newData);


echo $jsonResult;
```